# Android 5.0 device check current downloading file size

Tags: android, file, download, size

I have this code that can check finely the current size of downloading file if the device is under 5.0.

For example: My downloading file is 200MB and while downloading I check the file path and the file size < 200MB.

But from 5.0 it return the whole size of the file, it always return 200MB so I cannot set the progress to progress bar. Please help me.

```
filesize = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024));
```

Comment: start thread and put ur adapter in it and try set adapter notify changed, u could see the progress mb for test use up to 5 to 10 mb file in , try may it work , u could see file 1mb, 2 mb etc.. as per ur adapter got notifyed changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is the mechanism of Android 5.0. So I decided to change the way to get the current downloading file size by this code:

```
currentSize=cursorCheckCurrentSize.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
```

It will return the bytes downloaded of the downloading file and I can play around with the result